# What is the Best Logging method in Hadoop MapReduce java classes?

Tags: hadoop, logging, mapreduce, log4j, udf

I wrote classes which run on hadoop (2.1 or 2.2) as part of hive UDF/UDTF query. Eventually it runs as a Map/Reduce job.
The application performs various tasks, and I want to add logging based on log level.

I would like to know what is the best way (or the proper way) to do so.
Clearly I DO NOT want the logs to reside in some file on the data node that is not getting collected. I want hadoop to collect the logs so that we will be able to review all logs from a central location like the job tracker.

**Option-1:** the straight forward logging solution - print to system.out / system.err
I see lots of forums mentioning printing to system out or system err, but it will mean developing our own logging mechanism with debug levels etc...

```
System.out.println("my log message");
```

**Option-2:** using hadoop’s log4j commons logging
Other posts mention using apache commons logging.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MgrsIndexCommon.class);
LOG.trace(“my logging message”);
```

I used it, and it works, but I don’t have permissions to modify the logger configuration file. 
I am thinking of adding a feature to have log level in my applications configuration file, and modifying the log level from the java code. 
By the way I didn’t add a dependency to log4j in my pom.xml, and I used the one that comes with hadoop libraries.

If someone used this option, than how did you configure the logger?

**Option-3:** [log4j 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)
Some architect mentioned that we should look into adding log4j 2 dependency, and use it. Any suggestions in this area? If hadoop is using log4j can I bring my own log4j 2 and use it to write to hadoops logs?

Before I continue, I wanted to see if someone has good suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the `java.util.logging.Logger`, it will collect the logs in the job tracker.

For debugging java map reduce files you can use the logger for each class( driver, mapper, reducer ).

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

To inspect variables just use :

```
log.info( "varOne: " + varOne );
```

These log lines with be printed in the administration page for your job.

Answer (score 1):

I had Used slf4j, It is the wrapper around log4j and other logging libraries, If you need to change to some other logging library, you can, without changing actual code.

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WordCountExampleLoggingTest.class);
```

// Use it as

```
        LOG.error("Inseide Mapper");
        LOG.info("inside reducer ");
```

// For Logging configuration, add log4j.properies file in resources folder of your application.

```
ODS.LOG.DIR=/var/log/appLogs
ODS.LOG.INFO.FILE=application.log
ODS.LOG.ERROR.FILE=application_error.log
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, console
log4j.logger.com.ournamespace=ERROR, APP_APPENDER, ERROR_APPENDER

#
# console
# Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this
#

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}-%r %p %c{5}: %m%n

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER.File=${ODS.LOG.DIR}/${ODS.LOG.INFO.FILE}
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER.MaxFileSize=200MB
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}-%r %p %c{10}: %m%n


log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.File=${ODS.LOG.DIR}/${ODS.LOG.ERROR.FILE}
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.MaxFileSize=200MB
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=90
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}-%r %p %c{10}: %m%n
```

I can check the logs from ambari job tracker UI .
I hope that can help you.